Safety in industrial embedded system
I have just started working at a startup that specialises in imaging equipment in an industrial environment (based in Europe). I have just started a body of work looking to improve the safety standards of our product and I’ve hit the edges of my knowledge.
System Details:

24 V battery
10 A max current draw
Ambient temperatures between 30°C  and 50°C (sometimes in direct sunlight)
The system also has an auxiliary battery which facilitates safe shutdown of an onboard computer, 2 x 3 Li Ion 18650 Battery pack with integrated BMS’s

From a very basic risk assessment I have identified two main sources of potential risk:

The on board auxiliary battery
A set of high powered COB LEDs that
could get very hot if left on for a long time

A rough model of our current system looks like this:

Where load represents an onboard computer, control board, router etc..
We currently have an emergency switch which directly cuts the input power. This stops the COB LEDs from running but, due to the battery, the rest of the system continues to run.
I am looking to improve the system to something like this:

The key improvements I see to this are:

Power is now controlled through a relay rather than directly through the emergency switch.
Power is cut on both the high side of the battery and the low side. (The battery will also power the relay, not shown)

Questions that I have:

Is it better practice to use an emergency switch to drive a relay in
this way rather than directly in the circuit?

Are there relevant regulatory safety standards for a system in an
industrial system that we could use as a guide?

Does using a lithium ion battery in this context represent too high
of a risk? Should we try to design out the need for a battery or
perhaps use a different chemistry?



I think you're on a good path. But you'll nned to do a proper FMEA to make sure you're not missing anything. Think about each component failing in each state of operation and what it would cause (and what kind of steps to take to make the system not fail in a catastrophic manner or make it extremely unlikely to happen).

What does safety mean to you? Are you talking about functional safety? In the sense of IEC61508, Functional safety?

In many cases emergency switches are two pole. I prefered, when one was NO and the other one was NC. I built the system in a way that it would go into emergency stop (attention, there are different kinds of emergency stops) when one of them was triggered. This way i'm save against disconnection of the cable as well as short circuits.

The first guidance I was given about Emergency Stop buttons was that it should bring the equipment as quickly as possible into a maximally safe state, and not necessarily cut all power.  Cutting power is good for preventing electrocution, but bad if you want to use electric baking on a motor, for example, or give some kind of safety indication.  My question in your circuit would be: does cutting the battery power to the computer improve safety and if so how?  That's the first thing you need to know to resolve your issue.

As far as I can see, the EMG SWITCH is also used as an on-off switch.
As for your questions,

Is it better practice to use an emergency switch to drive a relay in this way rather than directly in the circuit?

Depends. Relays have an operating/release delay, generally a few to a few tens of milliseconds. So if the emergency release is really time-critical in your application i.e. even 1 ms is long enough then you may want to review the use of the relay. Also, some relays have mechanical issues such as contact welding, especially for high-current (e.g. 10A as in your case) applications, you need to make sure a safe and guaranteed release every time an emergency stop is needed.

Are there relevant regulatory safety standards for a system in an industrial system that we could use as a guide?

Depends on the what you mean by "safety". Functional, electrical or something else.

Does using a lithium ion battery in this context represent too high of a risk? Should we try to design out the need for a battery or perhaps use a different chemistry?

As far as I'm aware, Li-based batteries should not be used at environments having 40+ degC. You mentioned a max temp of 50°C but whether this is continuous or for limited time is not indicated. The BMS might have an over-temp protection if there's any temperature feedback from the battery, but still worth considering. Ignore if you have a forced-air cooling or a similar stuff.


Power is cut on both the high side of the battery and the low side. (The battery will also power the relay, not shown)

It's not shown this way in your 2nd diagram, unless you meant main input by "high-side", and aux input by "low-side".
One other thing I noticed in your 2nd diagram is that, although no details about the BMS are given, could there be a possibility of having the battery discharging through the output of the BMS when everything is switched off (e.g. emergency).

You might start with reading ISO 12100, mother of all machinery safety standards, which I recommend to anyone trying to address machine safety. Then find out if there is a specific safety standard (called a type-c standard) that addresses this type of machine. If found, that standard will reference requirements and other standards to apply.  For example, there might be a standard for safety of low-voltage high-intensity lighting equipment or for safety of imaging equipment that applies.
Regarding Emergency-Stop switch, the goal of such a device is complementary safety by allowing the operator to "cease all hazards", when operator recognizes an unsafe operating environment (e.g. untrained person too close to machine, jam in output from machine, large spill nearby, something fell onto machine, etc).  As others mentioned, this doesn't mean cut all power into machine (especially to an embedded computer) but typically means disable power to any output actuators that could be hazardous.  Also, simply clearing the e-stop switch to normal (run) position alone should not start the machine, rather operator should additionally need to press a reset or start button before machine hazards restart. But without a monitoring operator, e-stop does nothing for increased safety.
My quick read of the proposed change so far (with lots of assumptions), is that adding the relay doesn't improve LEDs turn off and now the e-stop switch also ungracefully shuts down the non-hazardous computer (as part of load). If the LED is the hazard, then allow both the e-stop switch and the controlling computer to disable the LED circuit.  Give the operator more control by requiring interaction with the computer to initially start the hazardous LED. Add sensor so the computer can detect e-stop switch run/stop, and require a computer interaction to restart the LED after e-stop is cleared. If LED can overheat, then add LED temperature sensor and logic to automatically turn off LED when exceeding safe temperature, report over-temperature problem to operator, and allow operator to restart after checking for problems. IMHO, the battery safety should be fully handled by the BMS, and if not, change to a new battery. Measure internal temp at battery under worst case environmental thermal load and verify battery doesn't exceed specification or that BMS correctly protects when exceeding max operating temperature.


Is it better practice to use an emergency switch to drive a relay in this way rather than directly in the circuit?

No. Plain relays are not suitable for safety functions since they are not failsafe and prone to weld, particularly so in high DC applications such as this. The same goes for the emergency stop switch itself, but they are designed with safety in mind. A 2 pole NC switch won't be hard to find, but one rated for 24VDC/10A might be. Make sure to read what DC it can handle.
You could be using safety relays, but they aren't doing you any good unless supervised. There are some pre-made safety relay modules you could use, but they are very expensive.

Are there relevant regulatory safety standards for a system in an industrial system that we could use as a guide?

As mentioned, the ISO 12100 for risk assessment. And for implementation, there is the general machine safety standard ISO 13849-1. Both of these are harmonized under the EU Machinery regulation and are very generic. There may also be application-specific standards for your type of product as well, which in that case will be more practical and hands-on.

Does using a lithium ion battery in this context represent too high of a risk? Should we try to design out the need for a battery or perhaps use a different chemistry?

Probably? 50°C is quite hot. What temperatures is it rated for?
